# Spaces and line breaks at the end of a shell script are not send to Espanso, how can I change that?

Tags: macos, shell, espanso

I have a shell script in Espanso (Mac) that I call. The output of the shell script is nicely given to Espanso so that it appears wherever I type.

However, I would like the output of my script to end with two enters: \n\n This is trimmed by Espanso. This also applies to spaces at the end of a text. Within my terminal, however, I can extend this output with spaces or enters. So it seems to go wrong with the connection between sh/bash and Espanso.

Example:

```
String: "Good afternoon,\n\n" 

Expected: "Good afternoon,

"

Output: "Good afternoon,"
```

--

```
String: "Hello,\n\nHow are you?\n\n"

Expected: "Hello,

How are you?

"

Output: "Hello,

How are you?"
```

--

```
String: "The problem is "

Expected: "The problem is "

Output: "The problem is"
```

So, enters and spaces within a string are send to the output, but at the line's end, they aren't. How can I bypass/disable this way of trimming?

I use it as you can find here: https://espanso.org/docs/matches/extensions/#shell-extension

Answer (score 0):

On Espanso v2.2.1 this is possible with cursor hints.

```
  - trigger: ":ga"
    replace: "Good afternoon,\n\n$|$"
```

Something important to note is the following warning in the documentation

[Cursor Hints](https://espanso.org/docs/matches/basics/#cursor-hints)

> This feature should be used with care in multiline expansions, as it may yield unexpected results when using it in code editors that support auto indenting. This is due to the way the feature is implemented: espanso simulates a series of left arrow key-presses to position the cursor in the correct position. This works perfectly in single line replacements or in non-autoindenting fields, but can be problematic in code editors, as they automatically insert indentations that modify the number of required presses in a way espanso is not capable to detect.